# Spherical harmonic plots with transparent sections

Tags: plotting, color

I'm trying to make density plots of spherical harmonics. I would like the low valued regions to be transparent. For example in the following plot I want everything but the red and yellow regions to be transparent so that all four such regions are visible.

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[
Re@SphericalHarmonicY[3, 2, ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], 
 ArcTan[x, y]], "CenterSphere", {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
ColorFunction -> 
Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, 
ColorData["ThermometerColors"][
Re[SphericalHarmonicY[3, 2, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, Boxed -> False, 
Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

Is there a way to get just the white part (in another color) and add transparency to the blue part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example in the [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) documentation under Applications just for this.

Create a new `ColorFunction` that adds an [`Opacity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html) directive.

```
ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[#], 
    ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#]] &)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. It would be nice if the sections of negative values were totally clear and the color gradient was applied to values grater than zero with increasing intensity.

Comment: I admit that this solution is much less hacky than mine =)